# Display error from 412 Precondition Failed, jQuery, $.post

Tags: jquery, json, post

Need some help with my code below, I have the first part working, but I'm not sure how to get the `.fail` to work.

If the email is wrong, name or last name blank you get a 412 Precondition Failed with a response

> {"email":"The Email field is required.","first_name":"The First name field is required.","last_name":"The Last name field is required."}

I need to display the message on the page within a div with a class `.errormessage`, but I can't get this working

```
 $('.bp_pop_holder').on('click', '#business_plus_form_add_submit', function() {
            $.post('/business_plus/add_customer_design/', $('.bp_pop_holder form').serialize(),
                    function(data) {
                        $('.bp_pop_holder tbody').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            var row = $('<tr />').data('customer_id', value.customer_id)
                                    .append($('<td />').addClass('current_email').text(value.email).width(170))
                                    .append($('<td />').addClass('current_name').text(value.first_name + ' ' + value.last_name).width(140))
                                    .append($('<td />').addClass('current_remove').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_person"></a>'));
                            $('.bp_pop_holder tbody').append(row);
                        })

                    }, 'json')
                    .fail(function() { 

                     alert("error"); 
                 });


             $('#business_plus_form_add').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        });
```

Thanks for the help.

I went for this is the end

```
.fail(function(data) { 
                    var res = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                    $('.error_message').empty();
                    $.each(res, function (key,value) {
                        $('.error_message').append(value+"<br/>");
                        }
                    ); 
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the function that you pass to the `.fail()` method takes a number of parameters, the first of these being a "jQuery XMLHttpRequest object" which is "a superset of the browser's native `XMLHttpRequest` object". You can use this object to interrogate the result of the HTTP request and get the data you require. For example:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR) {
    var responseCode = jqXHR.status;
    if(responseCode = 412) {
        var validationResult = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

        // validationResult now contains:
        //   {
        //       "email" : "The Email field is required.",
        //       "first_name" : "The First name field is required.",
        //       "last_name" : "The Last name field is required."
        //   }

        if('email' in validationResult) {
            alert(validationResult.email);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. im very new to this. to parse the string would it be something like 
alert (validationResult.emai);

Comment: The string that you get from `jqXHR.responseText` is a raw string in JSON format. To convert it into a JavaScript object, use `$.parseJSON`. Then you can access the properties of the object directly. I've updated my post to show how to do that.